# margin: 0 auto does not working

Tags: html, css, margin

I've read alot about this problem and I think I make everything right, but something is missing.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="text">some text</div> 
#text {margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px; display: block;    font-size: 24px; color: #000;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yKBQD/

Comment: You say it's not working, but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  Are you trying to center `div#text` within a larger containing element, or are you just trying to center "some text" within `div#text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `text-align: center` style, no `margin: 0 auto`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yKBQD/2/)**.

`margin: 0 auto` version would require another element within `div#text`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yKBQD/4/)**

Comment: Of course, I've been so into the margin, that i completely forgot about text-align. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Auto margins centre an element by increasing the left margin until it is equal to the right margin. If the element is wider then its container, then it will not shift the element at all. The JS Fiddle frame is rarely going to be over 1000 pixels wide.

Auto margins centre *an element*, not its content. You won't be able to see the position of an element (if it is as wide or wider than its container) unless you add a border, background, outline, etc so the edges become visible.

To centre inline elements and text inside an element, set `text-align: center` on the element containing them.